# Filter out IDs if contains certain vendor SQL

Tags: sql

I need to keep all job IDs associated with a specific vendor. If that vendor was included on that job, I need all jobID, not just the one with the vendor. There are multiple vendors under one jobid.

Example of my data set :

| JobID | Vendor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Vendor A |
| 1 | Vendor B |
| 1 | Vendor C |
| 2 | Vendor B |
| 2 | Vendor C |

I only want JobIDs associated with Vendor A, so my desired output would be

| JobID | Vendor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Vendor A |
| 1 | Vendor B |
| 1 | Vendor C |

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sub-query such as this:

```
Select *
from table1
where jobid in (select jobid from table1 where vendor = 'Vendor A')
```

Comment: I'm attempting this, the 2 columns come from two tables   I joined them already, but I am unsure how to reference both tables in the additional select function. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

A similar option is using a `JOIN` operation as follows:

```
SELECT tab.* 
FROM       tab
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT jobid FROM tab WHERE vendor = 'Vendor A') cte
        ON tab.jobid = cte.jobid
```

which combined with a index on the jobid field, can result in slightly better performance (depending on the volumes of your table).

Note: You can omit the `DISTINCT` keyword if the relationship between jobid and vendor is 1:1.

---

If your DBMS supports window functions, yet another approach is checking when there's at least one required vendor using the `MAX` function, then filter on it.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT JobID, Vendor, 
           MAX(Vendor = 'Vendor A') OVER(PARTITION BY JobID) AS has_vendor
    FROM tab
)
SELECT JobID, Vendor 
FROM cte 
WHERE has_vendor = 1
```